# examples for google cloud storage in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am looking for some examples on storing some data into Google cloud storage using gae and Java. Looking at the APIs I didn't see enough information.

Any sample code will really help us a lot.

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html 
and
http://www.rominirani.com/2010/03/17/episode-16-using-the-datastore-api
Could be good starting points. 

Are you looking for something More specific?

Comment: There are step-by-step instructions. What specifically is giving you trouble? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview.html

Comment: Hie when i try to store a object it says The lock for this file is not held by the current request. any help?

Comment: @Peter Knego - the upload example is not in java (at time of writing that page has a mixture of different languages independently of the setting at the top).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to set exclusive mode to true so that it remains locked by same request until object writing is completed

Comment: This answer has no relation to the original question.